# Suis-je le seul informaticien à dire "la" cache ?

Tags: genre, informatique

*La* cache d'armes de l'ETA, *la* cache de Ben Laden... Cache est clairement un substantif féminin. Mais, je passe pour un *alien* à employer le féminin quand je parle de *la* mémoire cache, ou simplement "*la*" cache, la cache de données en fait, là où l'ordinateur **cache** des données utilisées récemment ou fréquemment...

Ma question : suis-je le seul à employer le féminin ? Ai-je raison ?

Comment: *cache* is king, and king is masculin.

Answer (score 15):

*Cache* n'est pas exclusivement féminin: on dit aussi *le cache* au masculin dans d'autres domaines plutôt techniques, comme quand on parle d'un morceau de papier ou de carton utilisé pour "cacher" une partie d'une surface, pour par exemple ne pas y projeter de peinture. Même chose pour *le* cache d'un objectif photo.

Donc, il n'est pas absurde, illogique ou fautif d'utiliser également le masculin pour le même mot en informatique. C'est de toute manière l'usage qui l'emporte...

A titre personnel, je travaille également dans l'informatique, et je ne pense pas avoir jamais entendu autre chose que *le* cache.

Comment: Oui bien sûr, mais là on ne parle pas d'un couvercle sur des données, mais plutôt du contenant lui-même : le dépôt de données, données non-visibles facilement ou du tout par l'utilisateur, afin d'aller y piocher à la demande. C'est donc plus le sens de la cache d'armes, non ?

Comment: C'est vrai que ce serait plus logique,... mais l'usage l'emporte sur la logique... Je pense que *le cache* au sens informatique vient de  l'anglais *the cache* et a été "re-francisé", et ne vient pas directement du mot *cache* féminin français. Ce n'est alors pas le même "lexème" que *la cache*, c'est un terme différent, même s'ils ont une lointaine origine commune.

Comment: Oui, sauf que the cache anglais est un emprunt au français. Source : https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cache . Il semblerait donc, et ce n'est pas une exception, qu'il s'est produit un aller-retour avec changement de genre au passage... Quoi qu'il en soit, je continue à dire la cache, c'est "mon" usage, une forme d'expression de ma liberté en somme.

Comment: C'est la droit de chacun... : )

Comment: Presque... on ne trouve pas ta forme dans *le* dictionnaire...Et encore moins avec un sens logique. :-)

Comment: En parlant de dictionnaires, ceux que je consulte en ligne indiquent bien *cache* exclusivement comme nom masculin dans le sens de "mémoire cache": https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cache/11945/locution?q=cache#177917 https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cache#Nom_commun_2

Comment: J'ai bien un collègue qui dit "la wifi" alors pourquoi pas ;)

Comment: @Fabien Ce n'est pas la première fois qu'un mot a été réemprunté, vers l'anglais puis "rendu" :) À comparer : bœuf - **beef**steak - **bif**teck. Qu'on le souhaiterait ou non, l'usage l'emporte vs. l'étymologie également.

Comment: +1 Réponse au premier commentaire: Si, on parle bien ici d'**un cache** qui cache les données réelles, masque la structure, taille, organisation et est accessible plus rapidement, à l'image d'un couvercle. Il ne s'agit pas d'**une** cache (mot qui ne s'emploie de toute façon plus beaucoup, on dit plutôt aujourd'hui une cachette) où les données seraient dissimulées. Au contraire, les données sont plus facilement visibles et accessibles quand elles sont dans le cache dont on parle ici. Je n'ai jamais dit ni entendu *la cache* mémoire.

Comment: @jlliagre oui mais dans *le cache* ou bien *la mémoire cache*? Le sens premier du mot *cache* en anglais est celui d'un espace de stockage relativement rapide d'accès, ce n'est pas celui de cache dans cache-nez.

Comment: @qoba Le premier sens de cache en anglais (1797) est celui de la cache ou cachette (lieu où est caché quelque chose), comme en français (1558) puis *cache* s'étend pour nommer ce qui est caché dans la cachette (1830), le trésor (*hoard*). Ce dernier sens est absent du français *la cache*. réf. : https://www.etymonline.com/word/cache et Computer System Organization Par Naresh Jotwani p 129. (1974).

Comment: Et je ne vous dirai pas que j'ai hier entendu sur les ondes "la data", ouh là là ! Je n'en parlerai pas, hé hé.

Comment: Pourtant ce serait intéressant: en y pensant, je dis aussi "la data" pour désigner un le traffic qui passe sur un réseau mais qui n'est pas de la voix, mais "le big data" pour désigner l'exploitation de données stockées en très gros volumes. La data deviendrait masculine quand elle est "big"... Quelle langue de machos.... https://www.journalducm.com/big-data-revolution-numerique/

Answer (score 3):

L'usage est en effet très largement au masculin pour *le cache* ; en revanche on dit bien *la mémoire cache*.

Il s'agit en effet d'un aller-retour entre français et anglais avec changement de genre au passage.

*Une cache* en français c'est bien un endroit où sont cachées des choses, mais cet usage était déjà vieilli dans l'usage courant car [*cachette* l'avait souvent remplacé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+cache%2Cune+cachette&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20cache%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20cachette%3B%2Cc0), sauf pour des expressions comme effectivement *cache d'armes*. Ainsi les enfants jouant à cache-cache ne disent pas "j'ai trouvé ta cache" mais "j'ai trouvé ta cachette".

En ce qui concerne l'anglais *cache*, lui, il a acquis suite à son emprunt une forte connotation d'*entrepôt* secret, où se fait un certain *emmagasinement* jusqu'à ce que la capacité de stockage soit épuisée (puisque dans un endroit secret on doit souvent composer avec une surface limitée) (v. [définition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cache): *A store of things that may be required in the future*, donc bien un lieu d'emmagasinage). L'emprunt vient apparemment via le jargon des trappeurs canadiens où il avait ce sens d'[entrepôt](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cache) utilisé afin de pouvoir rester plus longtemps en campagne.

C'est après ce glissement de sens que le mot revient ensuite en français par l'informatique, où il se réfère moins à la notion d'une cachette secrète et plus à celle d'un espace de stockage (de données) qu'on remplit jusqu'à ras-bord.

Le mot ayant finalement pas mal changé de sens depuis son départ, et ayant été remplacé par *cachette* dans les usages les plus courants, s'est probablement retrouvé libre de se voir affublé d'un nouveau genre comme n'importe quel autre emprunt !

Comment: Les deux mots *cache*, au féminin et au masculin, ont été successivement repris en anglais. Dans *cache mémoire*, c'est *le cache* français (déverbal de cacher) qui a été repris, celui utilisé aussi dans *un cache-nez*.

Comment: @jlliagre hypothèse intéressante, pour ma part je suis sceptique, mais c'est peut-être parce que je suis trop familier du sens anglais "entrepôt". Comment pourrait-on savoir ? Y a-t-il un test qui permettrait de dire si c'est le même cache que cache-nez ?

Comment: +1 Je me suis fourvoyé avec mon cache-nez ;-) Il s'agit bien en effet d'une évolution de la cache(tte) mais suffisamment éloignée de l'acception française pour que le genre masculin ne pose pas de problème. Ce qui m'a trompé est que l'anglais *cache* peut signifier le lieu mais aussi le contenu du lieu, le trésor caché dans la cachette. Les premières occurrences de *cache memory* que j'ai trouvées font référence à ce dernier sens. La mémoire cache anglaise est donc une mémoire précieuse et cachée alors qu'en français, la mémoire cache est de la mémoire qui cache (masque) la mémoire principale.

Comment: @floquonsd'oùpepperx Je ne peux pas parler pour tous les informaticiens mais j'ai moi-même toujours compris cache comme signifiant une zone de mémoire située « devant » la « vraie » mémoire, donc effectivement comme un masque ou un filtre. Je n'ai donc jamais fait de lien entre cette mémoire et quelque chose de précieux que l'on dissimulerait dans une cachette.

Comment: @jlliagre c'est vrai qu'un cache peut aussi être vue comme un filtre qu'on met "devant" la mémoire et qui la cache. L'information qui est dans un cache y est copiée, elle n'y est pas *déplacée* comme c'est le cas pour des choses physiques. Je pense que l'emprunt est venu en français avec le sens identique à l'anglais (ça me semble être en général le cas des termes techniques qu'on emploie par manque d'équivalent suffisamment évident) mais c'est aussi possible qu'il continue de glisser en français vers le sens de filtre.

Comment: Cette dernière interprétation semble une meilleure explication du genre : pour éviter d'employer l'anglicisme pourtant lui-même emprunté au français, on parle bien d'antémémoire.

Comment: @chqrlie le terme d'antémémoire apparaît comme assez ancien et contemporain du terme anglais *cache*. Il semble avoir été créé pour l'occasion par IBM qui inventa la technique. Il serait intéressant de savoir ce que le traducteur de l'époque en pensait.

Answer (score 2):

Selon le [rapport 2007](http://www.ladocumentationfrancaise.fr/var/storage/rapports-publics/134000580.pdf) de la Commission générale de Terminologie de la langue française (p.44), *cache* est bien un nom masculin.

Sur l'origine de l'usage, je penche pour une distinction des concepts par différenciation de genre. *Une* cache reflète quelque chose de secret et difficilement accessible alors qu'*un* cache est tout l'inverse : l'accès y est rapide et facile et s'impose même souvent frontalement à qui veut lire des données.

Comment: On notera que dans certains navigateurs bien connus, "la" zone de cache (le zone ?) est quand même assez secrète et difficilement accessible. D'ailleurs son emplacement physique sur les disques change de chemin régulièrement, avec des noms codés d'un autre monde...

Answer (score 1):

Curieux, je prend mon dictionnaire Afnor de l'informatique (FR-EN/EN-FR).

Je trouve bien **cache (memory)** en Anglais.

Mais pas de **cache** en Français.

Sous **mémoire cache**, je vois *Cf. antémémoire*.

Conclusion: L'utilisation de **cache**, en Français et pour l'informatique, est un anglicisme; son genre *is up to you my dear* -- l'étymologie n'explique pas son genre... on pourrait adjoindre le neutre à la langue Française (kidding) :-)

J'avoue humblement n'avoir jamais utilisé antémémoire de ma vie ! (et pour ma part j'ai toujours utilisé le masculin pour cache).

Comment: Et si l'usage était devenu masculin par analogie avec le "cash" ? En effet, si l'on imagine que ce terme fut emprunté à l'anglais (donc un aller-retour) par des informaticiens français anglophones, voire des rapats, ils utilisaient probablement déjà "le cash" en substitution aux  espèces.

Comment: Le rapport signalé par @guillaume31 ci-après est plus récent que mon dictionnaire Afnor... donc va pour le n.m. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Suis-je le seul informaticien à dire “la” cache?

C'est bien la première fois que j'entends un tel usage. On dit bien *la mémoire-cache*, mais j'ai toujours entendu *le cache-mémoire* ou simplement *le cache*.

Le genre est masculin comme pour tous les mots composés commençant par *cache-* qui vient de l'action du verbe cacher. Le pluriel est donc *les cache-mémoires*. Il en est de même pour *cache-coeur*, *cache-col*, *cache-flamme*, *cache-misère*, *cache-nez*, *cache-pot*, *cache-sexe*...

En effet, le cache-mémoire n'est pas un endroit où l'on stocke une quantité limitée de mémoire pour les coups durs, mais un dispositif complexe qui évite les accès à la mémoire vive à l'extérieur du CPU, en cachant la mécanique d'accès. Les informaticiens abrègent *cache-mémoire* en *cache* en gardant le genre. L'usage s'est généralisé à tout dispositif qui accélérer l'accès à des ressources ou des résultats de calculs : base de données, navigation Internet, fonctions pures...

La même question se pose pour un autre terme largement utilisé en informatique : *l'espace*. Doit-on dire *une espace* comme dans l'industrie de l'imprimerie ou *un espace* comme l'abréviation d'un caractère d'espacement?  Je préfère *une espace*, mais je suis largement minoritaire.

Comment: On peut se demander à partir de combien de vues sur tel ou tel réseau social bien connu, un usage peut en remplacer un autre. Si demain j'attire un million de likes sur "le cache" et que 50.01% des usagers disent "le", est-ce légitime que l'usage devienne ce nouvel usage ?

Comment: @FabienHaddadi: AMHA pas plus légitime que de manipuler les électeurs... Mais je suppose qu'une poignée de contributeurs suffisamment influents peuvent faire évoluer l'usage.  Si tu veux faire un test, essaie de faire reculer la faute de persistante de la majorité des programmeurs français du mot anglais `integer` qu'ils prononcent *inn-té-gueur* au lieu de *inn-té-djeur* ;-)

Comment: Re: le dispositif complexe "qui évite les accès à la mémoire vive à l'extérieur du CPU": inexact, et non réservé exclusivement à la CPU. J'ai jamais parlé d'utilisation réservée aux coups durs d'ailleurs. Il peut s'agir d'une simple table dans une BDD, ou même d'un fichier à plat, avec système de pile FIFO. Il n'y a là aucun sens de cacher la mémoire comme on cacherait la misère, ou la poussière sous le tapis, mais plutôt de cacher un os comme le ferait un chien, pour utilisation ultérieure.

Comment: `integer`me rappelle le fameux cas du `varchar` (variable characters). Je viens de demander à mon collègue australien, et il me dit que "char" en dernière syllable se prononcerait à priori "tshar", mais, étant donné que c'est un mot-valise, on pourrait tout aussi bien le prononcer "varkar", et que du coup, c'est un choix personnel, de perception propre. ASHA.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi: choix personnel ou usage déconnecté de l'étymologie : même en anglais, on entend souvent GIF prononcé *djif* alors que l'abbreviation de *graphics information file* donnerait naturellement un G dur. Les Français prononcent très majoritairement *jif* alors que les Américains sont plus partagés.