# Le genre de « breakdance » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre, anglicismes, néologismes

Source: franceinfo : j'ai entendu aujourd'hui *le* *breakdance* (quand j'étais petit, on appelait ça du *smurf* en France) ; pourtant on dit *la* *dance*, et dans ce terme, *break* est un qualificatif : il ne s'agit pas ici de "dancebreak", comme on dirait *un* "lunchbreak".

Conscient que l'on a importé en français *break* comme un substantif masculin, et *dance* comme un substantif féminin, je suis surpris que breakdance fut importé comme masculin.

Alors, qui décide ? Le premier qui a parlé ? Le plus de *likes* ? Celui qui débarque du paquebot qui vient des US ? Comment ça marche, de nos jours ?

Comment: C'est un sujet qui te tient à cœur : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29913/suis-je-le-seul-informaticien-%C3%A0-dire-la-cache ;-)

Comment: Quand vous écrivez _la dance_ vous parlez d'un emploi du mot anglais en français ou du mot français _danse_ ?

Comment: @Jardin : bon point, effectivement je parlais de l'emprunt `dance`.

Answer (score 5):

C'est l'usage qui détermine le genre, comme il peut déterminer tout le reste, prononciation, orthographe, grammaire, définition, etc.

D'après Google Ngrams, ***breakdance*** semble avoir été d'abord principalement utilisé au masculin, mais le féminin a pris le dessus à partir du milieu des années 90, au moins à l'écrit :

[image]

Le masculin n'a cependant pas disparu, et bien que Google Ngram n'aie pas de données sur les dix dernières années, un nouveau retournement semble s'être produit.

Un petit tour sur le site de la fédération française de danse montre une certaine hétérogénéité, les deux genres étant utilisés mais un règlement officiel utilise le masculin :

> REGLEMENT TECHNIQUE ET SPORTIF DE LA DANSE HIP HOP
>   ...
>   1.1. Vocabulaire de la danse Hip-Hop :
>   Battle : Affrontement en danse entre deux personnes ou deux groupes. Chaque danseur évolue tour
>   à tour en musique, sans contact physique avec l’adversaire.
>   1.1.1. **Le breakdance**
>   **Le breakdance** est un style de danse qui s'est développé à New York dans les années 70. Les pratiquants de cette danse s'appellent les bboys (pour les garçons), les bgirls (pour les filles) ou breakeurs et breakeuses. Elle est caractérisée par son aspect acrobatique et ses figures au sol.
>   Cette danse est composée de danse debout (top-rock, up rock), avec de la danse au sol (foot-work), de la technique, des « freezes », des acrobaties et des « power moves ». C'est une danse qui demande une bonne hygiène de vie car le corps est très sollicité, ainsi que des capacités physiques et artistiques développées.

Je suppose que le masculin s'explique parce que les pratiquants, *les breakeurs et breakeuses*, doivent appeler ce sport ***le break***. C'est bien ce qui est fait ici : [Comment danser **le break**](https://fr.wikihow.com/danser-le-break). C'est aussi au masculin pour Martin Lejeune : [A 16 ans, ce Français est vice-champion olympique de breakdance et rêve de Paris 2024](https://rmcsport.bfmtv.com/mediaplayer/video/a-16-ans-ce-francais-est-vice-champion-olympique-de-breakdance-et-reve-de-paris-2024-1107565.html). Le masculin est aussi largement majoritaire dans les articles de presse récents, et pas seulement sur franceinfo.

En espagnol, le genre masculin semble largement majoritaire pour Google Ngram alors qu'en italien,  c'est le féminin qui prévaut (mais des recherches sur le web montrent les deux genres).

[image]

On ne schtroumpfe plus beaucoup le [smurf](https://fr.wiktionary), dont le nom est du à une confusion.

Le sujet du genre des néologismes et mots importés a de nombreuses fois été abordé ici.

Voir par exemple: [Comment décide-t-on du genre des néologismes en français? (How is the gender of new words decided in French?)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/322/comment-d%C3%A9cide-t-on-du-genre-des-n%C3%A9ologismes-en-fran%C3%A7ais-how-is-the-gender-of)

Comment: Bizarre... J'ai toujours entendu le breakdance ou du breakdance... Ca vient peut-être d'un emploi canadien comme la job, la breakdance. ^^

Comment: Merci pour cette recherche exhaustive. Je me demande sur quoi se base une rédaction de radio ou de TV avant d'adopter un genre.

Comment: Les choix des organes officiels et des compétiteurs ont certainement une influence notable.